# Magento - decimal points in invoice/be

Tags: php, magento, decimal-point

I need for my shop up to 4 decimal points. So far I followed some tuts and theyre working fine in front & backend for products. Only in sales/invoice prices,tax and totals are still rounded to 2 decimal points.

I've edited/overwrote following files:

```
\app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option.php
```

> somewhere around line 283 i changed  `return number_format($value, 2,
>   null, '');` in `return number_format($value, 4, null, '');`

```
\app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Helper\Form\Price.php
```

**same as in Option.php**

> \app\code\local\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php*   changed output of
>   function `roundPrice()` line 740 into `return round($price, 4);`
>
> \app\code\local\Mage\Directory\Model\Currency.php  in function
>   `format()` changed `formatPrecision` from 2 to 4 in line 197.
>
> \lib\Zend\Currency.php `$_options['precision']` changed from 2 to 4
>
> \app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\price\tier.phtml
>   `echo sprintf('%.2f', $_item['price']);` changed to `sprintf('%.4f',
>   $_item['price'])`

Ive looked into some core files like invoice.php or in adminhtml files if there are rounding stuff. But I couldnt find anything useful.

```
used extensions: (Magento 1.4.1.0)  
Asperience_DeleteAllOrders  
Flagbit_ChangeAttributeSet  
Mxperts_Invoice  
de_DE languagepack
```

thanks, greetz Rito

[image: magento round issue]

*(sorry for german in picture)*

Comment: Magento is very complex, there are many files and the function call stack is very deep. You should consider using a step-by-step debugger like XDebug or Zend Debugger to find where your problem is. Personally, I coded with Magento 6 months ago and I was keeping doing remote debugging with PDT/XDebug. At least once a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"totals" was a good hint, thx to Jonathan Day

Heres the solution for sales/invoice with four decimal points.

*\app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Items\Abstract.php*
change following code:
Line 292: `function displayPrices()` change to `return $this->displayRoundedPrices($basePrice, $price, 4, $strong, $separator);`
Line 305: `$precision=2` into `$precision`

*\app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php*
line 1358:

```
public function formatPrice($price, $addBrackets = false)
    {
        return $this->formatPricePrecision($price, 4, $addBrackets);
    }
```

I know its very dirty, but it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to turn on the Frontend and Backend Hints (`System>Config>Advanced>Developer`) so you can see which Block and which phtml View is responsible for rendering the 2 decimal place content. If you install the [Developer Toolbar extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Mage-World/extension/2271/mw_developertoolbar), you'll find that much easier.

Looking at your screenshot, I think that comes from the Admin Sales Order view, and therefore the phtml files under `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/totals` and the Blocks = `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Totals_Default` are a good place to look. The `formatPrice` function seems to be using Store.php that you have overridden, and some of the Currency files.

I suspect that @greg0ire is correct, this one is going to take some remote debugging to track down.  It's possible that your `$options['precision']` is being overwritten somewhere, so you need to see it's value at the time of execution.

Good luck, 
JD

P.S. I assume you have cleared and disabled cache...  Note that the adminhtml cache is **not** cleared in the `System>Cache Management` GUI, you must manually delete the files in `var/cache`.

Answer (score 0):

Found out a different simple way in magento 1.5.1

Got to code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php

change line number 194.

public function format($price, $options=array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
     {
        return $this->formatPrecision($price, 0, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
     }

0 - Denotes the precision point for price.